# Psutil storage values appear to be mathematically inaccurate

Tags: python, macos, psutil

When I run the following code:

```
import psutil
print(psutil.virtual_memory())
```

and receive the following output; no errors:
`svmem(total=8589934592, available=378863616, percent=95.6, used=893149184, free=18837504, active=363634688, inactive=352071680, wired=529514496)`

My macOS Activity Monitor gives me the following results:
[MacOs Activity Monitor App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjSDN.png)

What I don't understand is:

- How, if 95.6% of my RAM is being used, only 0.8GB out of 8GB is being shown as used (in terms of bytes); and not the 7GB my Activity Monitor shows.
- Why my output doesn't contain the amount of cached and buffered storage (shows in psutil PyPI demo).
- And why TOTAL - USED - FREE ≠ 0? Shouldn't that be zero (it is in the psutil PyPI examples)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- From the [psutil documentations](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory):

> used: memory used, calculated differently depending on the platform
> and designed for informational purposes only. total - free does not
> necessarily match used.
>
> Note: if you just want to know how much physical memory is left in a
> cross platform fashion simply rely on the available field.

- Buffers, cached, and shared memory values are only measured on Linux and BSD.
- You cannot actually say `total - (used + free)`. Again from the [documentations](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory):

> free: memory not being used at all (zeroed) that is readily available;
> note that this doesn’t reflect the actual memory available (use
> available instead). total - used does not necessarily match free.

Since Activity Monitor does not show the values in real-time, there is still a little bit of difference between `Memory Used` from Activity Monitor and `total - available` of psutil.

Comment: Thank you so much. By any chance do you know how we may compute the cached memory on a Mac? Preferable while using psutil.

Comment: @gubguD Unfortunately no, I don't. But, I found this link with a little bit of Googling. It might solve your problem: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/423717